# Adding labels to stripchart?

Tags: r, graph, plot

[stripchart](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/stripchart.html) :

```
x <- c(2, 8, 11, 19)
stripchart(x)
```

[image]

**How do you add labels 2, 8, 11, 19 next to the points?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text` and specify the `y` position.  The stripchart is drawn with `y=1`, so `text(x, y=1.1, ...)` will draw the labels slightly above the points.

```
x <- c(2, 8, 11, 19)
stripchart(x)
text(x, 1.1, labels=x)
```

[image]

Comment: That only works as long as the values are clearly separated. As soon as you jitter / stack the values this breaks down, and is not trivial to fix.