# Manually creating a legend when you can't supply a color aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

In attempting to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066131/can-data-points-be-labeled-in-stripcharts#34068263), one way to create the desired plot was to use `geom_dotplot` from `ggplot2` as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

CTscores <- read.csv(text="initials,total,interest,slides,presentation
CU,1.6,1.7,1.5,1.6
DS,1.6,1.7,1.5,1.7
VA,1.7,1.5,1.5,2.1
MB,2.3,2.0,2.1,2.9
HS,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.0
LS,1.8,1.8,1.5,2.0")

CTscores.m = melt(CTscores, id.var="initials")

ggplot(CTscores.m, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="up",binwidth=0.03) +
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

In order to distinguish the points, it would be convenient to just add color, but `geom_dotplot` chokes on color and doesn't end up stacking them:

```
ggplot(CTscores.m, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=initials)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="up",binwidth=0.03,color=NA) +
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Color can be added manually using a hack, though:

```
gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length=n+1)
  hcl(h=hues, l=65, c=100)[1:n]
}

cols <- rep(gg_color_hue(6),4)

ggplot(CTscores.m, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="up",binwidth=0.03,fill=cols,color=NA) +
  theme_bw()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Unfortunately, there's no legend.  On top of that we can't use `aes(fill=)` to try to add a legend manually because it will collapse the dots.  Is there any way to add a legend without using `aes()`?

Comment: You could use the same method as used in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13649473/1412059).

Comment: @Roland That did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `gtable` package you can extract the legend from the plot with the legend which fails to stack the dots and add that legend with `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package to the plot with the colored ans stacked dots as follows:

```
p1 <- ggplot(CTscores.m, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="up", binwidth=0.03, fill=cols, color=NA) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(CTscores.m, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=initials)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="up", binwidth=0.03, color=NA) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()

library(gtable)
fill.legend <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2)), "guide-box") 
legGrob <- grobTree(fill.legend)

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, legGrob, ncol=2, widths = c(4,1))
```

which gives:

[image]